# Web Redirect URL - developer.venmo.com

Tags: ios, braintree, venmo

I am trying to create App on venmo.com
I am Stucked at the field asking for "Web Redirect URL". Venmo docs says it is the one that will allow user to redirect back to my app from Venmo. My understand says it should be the URL scheme that is in my plist. But the docs also suggest that Web redirect URL will begin with "http:" or "https". My URL Scheme starts with com.appname. Can someone suggest me as what I need to input in "Web Redirect URL".

Comment: http or https is just a protocol, you can put it in front of your URL like: `http://com.appname.rest`
Not familiar with Venmo or whatever, so I can't tell what you need to do ..

Comment: My concern is specifically for Venmo. Without appropriate URL, they won't allow me to proceed :(

Comment: Could you give me the doc you found? or copy paste or whatever

Comment: https://developer.venmo.com/docs/quickstart

I am referring to "Build your App" -> point 1, on the above URL.

Comment: I tried my URL Scheme with http and without http. Also the other server URL which used in my app. But no luck as of now.